# Would it be possible for someone to validate this probability question solution for me?

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Let A,B,C be three events with P(A) = 2/7, P(B) = 1/4, P(C) = 1/2

If A and B are independent, can the inequality P($A\cup B \cup C$) < 1 be false?

**Attempt**

P($A \cap B$) = P(A) * P(B)

P($A \cap B$) = 1/14

P($A \cup B$) = P(A) + P(B) - P($A \cap B$) = 10/14

If $A \cup B$ and C are mutually exclusive:

P($A \cup B$) + P(C) = 10/14 + 1/2 > 1

Therefore the inequality can be false

Comment: If $P(F) = 3/4, P(G) = 1/2$ and $F$ and $G$ are mutually exclusive does it mean $P(F\cap G) = 5/4$? No, it does not. But it does mean that $F$ and $G$ cannot be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Therefore the inequality can be false if the two events are mutually exclusive? Or am i looking for the case where P(∪∪)  = 1?

Comment: Not following.  Do you want $A,B$ to be independent or do you want them to be mutually exclusive?  Can't have both.

Comment: I first wanted to check if the events could be mutually exclusive. I incorrectly reasoned that in that case since P(∪) + P(C) = 10/14 + 1/2 > 1 the inequality could be false. However, all I actually showed was that ∪ and C must be independent events. Therefore I think all I have to show now is whether the inequality holds if the two events are independent? (I believe it does, therefore cannot be false)

Comment: Not following.  The assumption is that $A,B$ are independent.  That's how the problem reads.  The case where they are mutually exclusive has nothing to do with it.  And, more generally, there are lots of cases other than "mutually exclusive " and "independent".

Comment: If ∪ and C are mutually exclusive: Please refer to this line

Comment: @treebluefire What I mean is that if the sum of probabilities of two events is more than 1 then the events cannot be mutually exclusive. In you case, when you say "If $A\cup B$ and $C$ are mutually exclusive..." the assumption would be wrong to begin with, that is if you computed $P(A\cup B)$ correctly. But I believe there is an error in your computation there.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Good.  But $\frac 27+\frac 14-\frac 1{14}\neq \frac {10}{14}$.

Comment: Ah yes, that is a mistake, but even in the situation where that was correct, this would not be the correct way to approach the proof. Can you give any tips on how you would?

Comment: Your method, now that I understand it, is fine.  The numbers threw me off.  When you fix them, you should get that $\frac 27+\frac 14-\frac 1{14}=\frac 12$ so you see that, when you consider the case where $A\cap B$ and  $C$ are mutually exclusive (as you did) you now get exactly $1$, which still violates the desired inequality.

Comment: Ah, that is wonderful! However, let us suggest a situation where it does not equal one, what would you try from there?

Comment: Your method is sound.  The extreme for the left hand is always realized when $A\cap B$ and $C$ are exclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible; $P(A \cup B \cup C) < 1$ always holds.

First off you need to understand that the only case that $P(A \cup B \cup C) < 1$ doesn't hold is when $P(A \cup B \cup C) = 1$ because the probability is always less than or equal to 1.

Now, since A and B are independent we have:
$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) = \frac{2}{7} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{2}{28} = \frac{13}{28}$$
Moreover:
$$
P(A \cup B \cup C) = P(A \cup B) + P(C) - P((A \cup B) \cap C) \leq P(A \cup B) + P(C) = \frac{13}{28} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{27}{28} \Rightarrow P(A \cup B \cup C) < 1
$$